# using @LoadBalanced with OAuth2RestTemplate cause class not found TypeToken

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

so, I was using simple RestTemplate with direct ip:port to my service:

```
restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8081/user", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class, new HashMap<String, String>());
```

but now I want to make it eureka-aware. So, so Ive added `@LoadBalanced` above my restTemplate. Ofcourse `myapp` here is a name of service registered in eureka.

```
@Autowired
@LoadBalanced
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

...
restTemplate.exchange("http://myapp/user", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class, new HashMap<String, String>());
...
```

but this breaks with:

```
ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey.<init>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:251)
at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey$1.<init>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:33)
at com.netflix.client.config.CommonClientConfigKey.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigKey.java:33)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.preprocess(EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

do I have to add any extra dependencies next to:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.cloud.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

?

Comment: what version is `${spring.cloud.version}`?

Comment: Its same as dependency above -1.0.1.RELEASE, sorry - forgot to change that

Comment: How about with `1.0.3.RELEASE`?

Comment: ive updated spring-cloud-starter-eureka to 1.0.3.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-security to 1.0.2.RELEASE - same issue